# Is an English version of the French phrase "un ange passe" used commonly?

Tags: phrases

I understand "un ange passe" is a French phrase, which is translated into English as  "an angel passes by" or something like that.
What does it mean and is it used commonly in English?

Comment: I've never encountered it, either as loanphrase or transliterated. Maybe because in American conversations, there's never a prolonged silence :) Though I did once say "*awwkwaaaard siiiilenceeee*" after such a pause in front of a bunch of new people I just met. I did succeed in braking the silence, but I didn't make it any less awkward...

Comment: Simon & Garfunkel once did a version of "[El Condor Pasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_C%C3%B3ndor_Pasa_%28song%29)," if that qualifies.

Comment: I may have seen it a few times in my 66 years, but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: FYI: I can attest to "Awkward turtle!" with an accompanying hand gesture, which I shall try to describe, being used by English teenagers around 3 or 4 years ago to break an awkward silence.
The gesture is to place one hand over the other in front of you, both palms down, then clasp the interlocking fingers, and stick the thumbs out to the sides.  Then rotate the thumbs in small circles, as if they were legs propelling the hands forwards.
Please don't ask me how this arose; even my children, who introduced this to me, have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search using Google ngram shows zero results in English.

[Google ngram: un ange passe:fre_2012,un ange passe:eng_2012](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un%20ange%20passe%3Afre_2012%2Cun%20ange%20passe%3Aeng_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20ange%20passe%3Afre_2012%3B%2Cc0)

Therefore I think it is safe to say it is not commonly used in English. Speaking personally this is the first time I've heard it.

Given that fact, the meaning of the phrase is out of scope in ELU. However
I think it is a good fit for [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/) where they allow questions and answers in English.

**Update**

My Google search was a little too quick. If you search with the *case-insensitive* tag enabled, there are some [results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un%20ange%20passe%3Afre_2012%2Cun%20ange%20passe%3Aeng_2012&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cun%20ange%20passe%3Afre_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BUn%20ange%20passe%3Afre_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20ange%20passe%3Afre_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CUn%20ange%20passe%3Aeng_2012%3B%2Cc0). Mostly they are French texts that are somehow in the English corpus.